# Google AppScript Moving Specific Cells to a Different Spreadsheet Based on the Value of the Contents of Other Cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I am attempting to write a script that will copy a few select cells from one spreadsheet into another based on the value of a few cells in the original spreadsheet (S1). If a job is won and moved into the "Closed - Won" sheet and it is a CSG job, I want four of the cells copied into a different spreadsheet (S2) so the project setup phase can begin.

In S1, when a job is won, it is automated to move itself to the "Closed - Won" sheet by changing the value of column 8 of that projects' row to "Closed - Won". It then copies the row from whatever page it is on, pastes it in the "Closed - Won" page, then deletes the row from the prime sheet. This was my first attempt at writing the code, which was just aimed at copying the projects that are already in "Closed - Won" if they are CSG projects.

```
function moveRows() {
     const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Closed - Won');
     const CSGSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ProjectIDHere').getSheetByName('Open Projects'); 
     const CSGLastRow = CSGSheet.getLastRow(); 

    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    let sortRange = sheet.getSheetValues(2,1,lastRow,9);

      Logger.log(lastRow)
     // Logger.log(typeof(sortRange))
     // Logger.log(sortRange.length))

    let CSGCounter = 1;

    for (var i = 1; i <= sortRange.length; i++) {
     let name = sheet.getRange(i,10).getValue();
     console.log(i + " - " + name);

         if (name == "CSG") {
            let rowValues = sheet.getRange( i, 2, 1, 1).getValues();
            CSGSheet.getRange(CSGLastRow+CSGCounter,2,1,1).setValues(rowValues)};
         if (name == "CSG") {
          let rowValues = sheet.getRange( i, 5 ,1, 1).getValues();
          CSGSheet.getRange(CSGLastRow+CSGCounter,3,1,1).setValues(rowValues)};
         if (name == "CSG") {
          let rowValues = sheet.getRange( i, 1 ,1, 1).getValues();
          CSGSheet.getRange(CSGLastRow+CSGCounter,5,1,1).setValues(rowValues)};
         if (name == "CSG") {
          let rowValues =  sheet.getRange( i, 9, 1, 1).getValues();
          CSGSheet.getRange(CSGLastRow+CSGCounter,6,1,1).setValues(rowValues)
          CSGCounter++};
      }

  }
```

When this went into play, it did copy over the correct cells to where I wanted them to be. Although sloppy, it did work. Once. When I ran this again, it copied the entire list of projects and their cells a second time, including the ones that had already been copied. I then got the idea to break apart the code I had written for when things changed pages within S1 and apply a new destination to it. That turns out to be more difficult that when I initially wrote the code for moving pages, because I had forgotten what the original code did when I was writing it. I have gotten as far as I can think of with this, named Attempt #3, because attempt #2 was a flaming pile of crap.

```
function attempt3(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const active = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const won = ss.getSheetByName('Closed - Won');
  const CSGSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ProjectIDHere').getSheetByName('Open Projects');
  const CSGLastRow = CSGSheet.getLastRow();
  
  

  if (e.range.getRow() > 2 && e.range.getColumn() == 8 && e.value == 'Closed - Won' && e.oldValue == "Closed" && active.getSheetName() == "Closed" && e.range.getColumn() == 10 && value == 'CSG'){ 
    // GETS FIRST VALUE FROM COLUMNN B TO PASTE IN ID COLUMN B
    var value1 = won.getRange(i,2).getValues();
    CSGSheet.getRange(CSGLastRow+1,1,1,2).setValues(value1);
    // GETS SECOND VALUE FROM COLUMN E TO PASTE IN ID COLUMN C
    var value2 = won.getRange(i,5).getValues();
    CSGSheet.getRange(CSGLastRow+1,1,1,3).setValues(value2);
    // GETS THIRD VALUE FROM COLUMN I TO PASTE IN ID COLUMN F
    var value3 = won.getRange(i,9).getValues();
    CSGSheet.getRange(CSGLastRow+1,1,1,6).setValues(value3);
    // GETS FOURTH VALUE FROM COLUMN A TO PASTE IN ID COLUMN E
    var value4 = won.getRange(i,1).getValues();
    CSGSheet.getRange(CSGLastRow+1,1,1,5).setValues(value4);}
}
```

Now that I have hit a brick wall with the code I have written, I was wondering if any of you might have a potential fix in mind. Currently it runs, has no hangups on the execution of the code but there is no transferring of information from one spreadsheet to the next. Honeslty there is a very good chance it is because of a semicolon or curly bracket being put in the wrong place. I currently am only focused on moving things from the "Closed" page to the "Closed - Won" stage because it can be duplicated once it works correctly.